# How to invoke a command from string?

Tags: powershell

Whenever I attempt to invoke a command from a string, I get a syntax error.

This is for a makeshift console for certain users, but I only want certain custom commands to be allowed.

I have already tried the following:
&$functionName $paramater1 $paramater2
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$functionName $paramater1 $paramater2}

```
Write-Host 'READY>' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta;$inputx = Read-Host;$input = $inputx.Split()
if (Get-Command $cmdName -errorAction SilentlyContinue){ # Checks if function is available
    # Execute exact string
}
```

What is expected:

Say we input `"Write-Host 'Hello World!' -NoNewLine"`
Command to execute: `Write-Host 'Hello World!' -NoNewLine`

What is returned:

`At line:1 char:44
+ Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$functionName $paramater1 $paramater2}
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$paramater1' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:56
+ Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$functionName $paramater1 $paramater2}
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '$paramater2' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Create a joint string from the separated string and use Invoke-Expression $command.

This is some really blocky and horrible programming on my part, which can easily be simplified, but here is the original block fix.

```
Write-Host 'READY>' -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Magenta;$inputx = Read-Host;$input = $inputx.Split()
if (Get-Command $cmdName -errorAction SilentlyContinue){
    if($input[0] -eq $null){
        write error 'Empty command'
    }else{
    if($input[1] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[2] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[3] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[4] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]+" "+$input[4]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    if($input[5] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]+" "+$input[4]+" "+$input[5]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[6] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]+" "+$input[4]+" "+$input[5]+" "+$input[6]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[7] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]+" "+$input[4]+" "+$input[5]+" "+$input[6]+" "+$input[7]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[8] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]+" "+$input[4]+" "+$input[5]+" "+$input[6]+" "+$input[7]+" "+$input[8]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[9] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]+" "+$input[4]+" "+$input[5]+" "+$input[6]+" "+$input[7]+" "+$input[8]+" "+$input[9]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }else{
    if($input[10] -eq $null){
        $command = $input[0]+" "+$input[1]+" "+$input[2]+" "+$input[3]+" "+$input[4]+" "+$input[5]+" "+$input[6]+" "+$input[7]+" "+$input[8]+" "+$input[9]+" "+$input[10]
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }}}}}}}}}}}
}
```